# Trouble with backup on SBS2008

Tags: backup, windows-sbs

We have an SBS2008 installation, which has a backup task. It creates a backup twice a day onto external storage.  This worked for a long time.

But the backup can't be performed now. The last valid backup was before some Exchange updates, SBS Update Rollup 8 and SharePoint updates were installed.

The only error in Event Logs is for VSS (the Volume Shadow Service), which I only have in German.

Things I've done:

- restart the server
- chkdsk /r /f for all volumes
- restart the VSS service
- googling
- manual backup

Nothing's helped.

How can I set up the backup again?

Edit:

- i use the built in backup tool
- Service Pack 2 is set up (Exchange)

Edit2: vssadmin list writers output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>vssadmin list writers
vssadmin 1.1 - Verwaltungsbefehlszeilenprogramm des Volumeschattenkopie-Dienstes

(C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.

    Verfassername: "System Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {4a3826f5-0abb-4272-b2bd-834c64e1d5ab}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "SqlServerWriter"
   Verfasserkennung: {a65faa63-5ea8-4ebc-9dbd-a0c4db26912a}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {5a4cd418-4946-44d5-9c33-f64d1c0b88ca}
   Status: [8] Fehlgeschlagen
   Letzter Fehler: Nicht-wiederholbarer Fehler

Verfassername: "FRS Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {d76f5a28-3092-4589-ba48-2958fb88ce29}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {e503b4be-3eb7-40b2-9af0-c583bc16dea6}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "ASR Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {be000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {1603b986-490b-4def-85c7-a27f3c1b6554}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "FSRM Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {12ce4370-5bb7-4c58-a76a-e5d5097e3674}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {ab0c47b4-5151-43aa-9662-f1e0a0c61979}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "IIS Metabase Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {59b1f0cf-90ef-465f-9609-6ca8b2938366}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {db444c69-4b95-4973-92b8-fd6b6a231384}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "Certificate Authority"
   Verfasserkennung: {6f5b15b5-da24-4d88-b737-63063e3a1f86}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {9d9052aa-ee49-4d35-9d9a-04c9bee5185a}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "IIS Config Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {2a40fd15-dfca-4aa8-a654-1f8c654603f6}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {378a9ae7-3ce7-41d5-aa55-37378d64b83d}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "NTDS"
   Verfasserkennung: {b2014c9e-8711-4c5c-a5a9-3cf384484757}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {af5f3cdb-8484-4ce4-a7b9-b7d791e4d115}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "Registry Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {fc9dfee0-30eb-432c-acd3-2619451313d5}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "Microsoft Exchange Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {76fe1ac4-15f7-4bcd-987e-8e1acb462fb7}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {a94b5972-9861-405e-b285-f801e5723c81}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "COM+ REGDB Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {61445d53-fa1d-428b-b808-5010646489ed}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "Shadow Copy Optimization Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {d8138f0c-d2bd-46f6-80ff-3a9842c2397b}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "TS Gateway Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {368753ec-572e-4fc7-b4b9-ccd9bdc624cb}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {1c7c28a1-9147-4c41-aef9-244eba07c198}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "SPSearch VSS Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {57af97e4-4a76-4ace-a756-d11e8f0294c7}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {00bd089b-95ff-44be-80d7-10f9fe2bc86b}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "WMI Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {df69f5f3-14f0-49c3-8968-91796110908d}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "BITS Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {4969d978-be47-48b0-b100-f328f07ac1e0}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {58919c7b-140b-4e11-97e0-a9b6c86ba0cb}
   Status: [1] Stabil
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "NPS VSS Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {35e81631-13e1-48db-97fc-d5bc721bb18a}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {3e83ea26-fe12-4bc1-81ca-4c03fcebf5df}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler

Verfassername: "Dhcp Jet Writer"
   Verfasserkennung: {be9ac81e-3619-421f-920f-4c6fea9e93ad}
   Verfasserinstanzkennung: {08068f03-edc4-4d6f-a756-6384a8f4c6a9}
   Status: [5] Warten auf Fertigstellen
   Letzter Fehler: Kein Fehler
```

## EDIT 3: #

It seems to be like the SqlServerWriter is the troublemaker, If i stop the service, backup is possible. Is there a fix for this? I don't want stop the Service everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows' built-in backup, or a 3rd party tool?

Did a quick search and found a very similar issue in another forum.  Here's the answer from an MSFT:

1. Besides the Rollup 9 update, have you installed the Service Pack 2 for Exchange server 2007?
2. Have you checked the backup destination disk and make sure there are sufficient free space for the SBS backup? If you are using external USB storage, you may
   try another one to test.
3. Have you check the WMI service? Make sure the WMI service is Automatic and Started, e.g. try to run "MSinfo32.exe" program to verify WMI service is running
   normally.

Run the following command from command prompt on the SBS server:

```
cd windows\system32
Net stop vss
Net stop swprv
regsvr32 ole32.dll
regsvr32 vss_ps.dll
Vssvc /Register
regsvr32 /i swprv.dll
regsvr32 /i eventcls.dll
regsvr32 es.dll
regsvr32 stdprov.dll
regsvr32 vssui.dll
regsvr32 msxml.dll
regsvr32 msxml3.dll
regsvr32 msxml4.dll
Net start swprv
Net start vss
```

Perform a backup operation to verify that the issue is resolved.

After completing the registration, in command prompt type:
vssadmin
list writers

Then please check if there is any errors with listed writers. Also, If there are 3rd party backup and antivirus software installed, like Backup Exec or Norton AV, please
temporarily disable all of them for test purpose.

Good luck!

Comment: 1. yes, SP2 is set up
2. theres enough Space ( twice as the volumes are big)
3. what's WMI exactly? -> informations about system where displayed

error on following commands: regsvr32 /i eventcls.dll / regsvr32 es.dll / regsvr32 msxml.dll / regsvr32 msxml4.dll

still broken.

Comment: found the problem in VSS Writer for SQL, any suggestion?